# Jquery gallery slider

Tags: jquery

Hi will some one help me to find a free script something like this website has

http://www.paris-beyrouth.org/

Answer (score 1):

Try [Spritely](http://www.spritely.net/). It's MIT and GPL licensed. Spritely can do it with either scrolling backgrounds or sprites.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty cool. I don't know if you would be interested, but I am in the process of developing a slideshow plugin for jQ.

http://www.simplesli.de

I'm still working out the kinks on the site and in the code, but if you're interested, keep an eye out.

Comment: Link in answer dead.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like its using the following jquery plugins:

```
/* compact [
2 prive/javascript/jquery.js
3 prive/javascript/jquery.form.js
4 prive/javascript/ajaxCallback.js
5 plugins/auto/spip_out_ouvrant/spip_out_ouvrants.js
6 squelettes/javascript/jquery.easing.1.3.js
7] 60.9% */
```

The set up of the image gallery looks like just three images that have a lot of animation connecting them together using the [easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/).

Good use of jQuery instead of flash.